# How to replace the values in a pandas dataframe with values looked up from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2 dimensional dataframe, `swap_dates`, which looks as follows:

[image: df1]

I also have a dataframe, `proj_zcb`, with a single column which looks like this:

[image: df2]

I'm hoping to replace the dates in the first dataframe with the respective values from the second dataframe (or, equivalently, dictionary).

I have tried using pandas' [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function;

```
swap_dates.replace(proj_zcb.to_dict())
```

but for some reason this does not seem to work;

[image: df3]

Can anyone see why this might not be working or, alternatively, suggest an approach that works?

Comment: Please don't use an image as a sample code. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The replace function works on `lists` and `dicts`. So as long as you follow this it should be fine. (The only issue might be dates).

for lists:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

print(df)
df.replace([0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2, 1])

print(df)
```

for dicts:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

print(df)

# replace
df_new = df.replace({'A': 0, 'B': 5}, 100)

print(df_new)
```

Your question is of type `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason that the code

```
swap_dates.replace(proj_zcb.to_dict())
```

did not work is because `proj_zcb.to_dict()` returns a dictionary of dictionaries (i.e. a dictionary whose keys are the column names of `proj_zcb` and whose elements are dictionaries created from those columns).

The following code worked as hoped:

```
swap_dates.replace(proj_zcb.to_dict()['Proj ZCB'])
```